# How do you convert ColdFusion files stores in a .zip file into a .war filecompile Coldfusion code?

Tags: coldfusion, zip, war

I downloaded Coldfusion 10, opened the ColdFusion administrator, followed these steps, and all I ended up with The idea is a 250 MB .war file that has nothing to do with the .zip files I am trying to convert. I'm clearly missing the pointcompile then package. Can someone help?

1. Open the ColdFusion Administrator.
2. Specify a unique name for the archive file (no extension) in the Archive Name field.
3. Click Add. The Add New Archive screen appears.
4. Specify archive settings on the Add New Archive screen.
5. Click Create. ColdFusion creates an EAR or WAR file in the specified application distribution directory.

Comment: What? What zip files are you trying to convert? And what are you trying to convert them to?

Comment: What you are trying to do in plain english? The question title suggests one thing and the description another ...

Comment: All of the cfm files stored inside a zip file need to go into a war file

Comment: It seems there is at least one step between #1 & #2 on your list of steps. Where did you find these steps ( I tried finding anything that looks like what you mention and cannot find anything)? Can you give us a better idea of what it is you are trying to do (and please do not say 'put .zip into .war', you said that already and it is still confusing)

Comment: Why do you have a .zip file full of .cfm files?  Where did that .zip file come from?  Did you make it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A .war file is just a .zip file with a different extension that contains the needed files to run in a servlet container or application server. If *your* zip file already contains all of those files (WEB-INF, etc) then you need only rename the file from .zip to .war.

If *your* zip file is just a zip of your CF files from a site and you are trying to redeploy it as a .war then, after creating the .war file you would need to unpack it, copy the files into the appropriate place, and create a new .war.

You really don't provide much to go on, so I cannot offer much more.

UPDATE:
I will add, that the easiest way to deploy a new CF .war would be to deploy the .war that the CF installer created on a servlet container (Tomcat, for example). The servlet container should unpack it and deploy it. Once you have confirmed that CF is running, you can then copy your CF files (not in a .zip file) to the folder that was created for that app (by default it is usually called /cfusion).

Comment: You didn't answer the question. Obviously I need the "special" files and folders that belong to a WAR file. Renaming a ZIP file to WAR file will not magically add those files and folders to the archive.

Comment: Did I say that renaming a .zip to a .war would magically add those files?  Or did I do my best to answer your poorly written question only to have you be an ingracious ass about it?